# Why is $H$ not a subgroup of $G$?

Tags: group-theory

This may be a stupid question, but

let's consider the cyclic group $G=(\mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z},+)=\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$.

By Lagrange's Theorem this group can only have subgroups of order $2$ or $5$, since its order is $10$.

So for example the group $H=(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z},+)=\{0,1,2\}$ is not a subgroup of $G$, since its order is $3$ and $3$ is not a divisor of $10$.

But it is closed under the group operation, has the neutral element $0$ of $G$ and every element has its inverse, so the subgroup properties are there.

Clearly, I am making some kind of mistake here, but I can't see it.

Comment: in $H$ the binary operation is addition modulo 3. but in $G$ it is addition modulo 10. when you consider $H$ it is not closed under addition modulo 10.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For $H$ to be a subgroup of $G$ it must not only be the case that every element of $H$ is in $G$ but also that *the group operation is the same*.

This is not the case here -- for example, we have $2+2=4$ in $G$, but $2+2=1$ in $H$.

So the group operation on $H$ is not just the restriction of $G$'s group operation to the elements of $H$, and therefore $H$ is not a subgroup.

Answer (score 2):

In the big group, $1$ has $9$ as an inverse. But $9 mod 3=0$. So in the "subgroup" you'd expect $1+0=0$. So you're going to have problems. The "subgroup" expects $2$ to be the inverse of $1$.

Answer (score 2):

The operation in $H$ is not the same as in $G$. If you are using $+$ from the group $G$, then $2+2=4$ and $4\notin H$. $H$ is not closed under $+$ defined for $G$, so it is not a group, hence not a subgroup of $G$.

Answer (score 0):

In $H$ the binary operation is addition modulo 3. but in $G$ it is addition modulo 10. when you consider $H$ it is not closed under addition modulo 10.